# Full functions list for SugarCRM Studio

Tags: crm, sugarcrm

I am learning to use SugarCRM and have noticed that the functions list for the studio when setting up calculated fields is incomplete/missing out functions. I have searched the internet but seen no "complete" list of functions, I was wondering whether there was any way of me finding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i am correct , i think  you are searching where the all calculated formulas save defined by Sugar, So you need to go ,

```
include/expressions/expression
```

and check there you will find , you can create your own formulas also if you want.